# whose view is not in the window hierarchy - email form

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, hierarchy, appdelegate

I'm calling a method from viewcontroller in an appdelegate. When I was testing functionality I just used NSLog message which works fine (so the connection between viewcontroller and appdelegate is OK). The problem appears once I add a email form into this method. The message I receive is:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <MFMailComposeViewController: 0x1fdc3990> on <ViewController: 0x1fd9e3b0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Anyone who know what to do? I know there are lot of topics with 'whose view is not in the window hierarchy' issue but none of them helped me.

ViewController.m

```
...
-(void)mail{
    NSLog(@"blablabla");
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

        MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mail setSubject:@"Hello and welcome!"];

        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"tomas.javnicky@gmail.com"];
        [mail setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        [mail setCcRecipients:toRecipients];

        NSString *emailBody = @"Hey all!";
        [mail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

        mail.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
        [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];


    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                                        message:@"E-mail is not supported on your device"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{

    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"mail failed");
            break;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                             completion:nil];
}
...
```

Appdelegate.m

```
...
-(void)something {
     ViewController * vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
     [vc mail];
}
...
```

This is what solved my problem:

```
- (void)something {
    ViewController *rootViewController = (ViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    [rootViewController mail];
}
```

Also check the answer by rmaddy for more info.

Comment: Update your question with the code used to show the mail composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've posted code, the problem is obvious. You create a view controller but you never display it (in the `something` method). Then you call a method on this undisplayed view controller (`mail`) which attempts to display the mail view controller from the undisplayed view controller. This is what causes the error.

You need to display the mail controller from a view controller that is already being displayed (such as the `rootViewController` maybe).

What is the point of your `ViewController` class?

Comment: could you please write down the edit of my code? I don't really understand what do you mean

Comment: What part don't you get? You are trying to present the mail controller from an undisplayed view controller. You can't do that. Change your code so you present the mail controller from a view controller that is currently being shown to the user.

Comment: But how? I think the view controller that is displayed is ViewController. isnt it? I would still actually prefer code example instead of theory.

Comment: No, you are creating a new `ViewController`. If you already have a displayed `ViewController`, call the `mail` method on the one that is already displayed, do not create a new one like you do in your `something` method.

Comment: And what if I'm using more view controllers in my app? How can I present the mail controller from the view controller that's currently being shown?

Comment: You need to get a reference to the topmost view controller so you can present from there. There are various ways to do this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374209/get-reference-to-top-viewcontroller-in-ios as one way.