# Cannot get segue to work with viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

For my view controller's viewDidLoad method implementation, it asks the user for address book access. I need to make it so that if the user taps the "Don't allow" button on the alert view window, then we will segue them to another view controller.

My problem is that the segue never happens and shows this output in the console:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <MediaCaptureVC: 0x156788c0> on <AddFriendsViewController: 0x15670dd0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I have tried several things that have not helped:

1. Adding a `viewDidAppear` method implementation with my segue code inside of it and calling `[self viewDidAppear]` in my viewDidLoad's if statement.
2. Moving my segue code to the very bottom of `viewDidLoad`.

But nothing works. I need a way to trigger the segue even if the view technically is loading because if they deny access to their address book then there is absolutely no reason for them to stay on the view controller.

Here is the beginning of my `viewDidLoad` method implementation where I ask for address book access, and then my if statement of `if(accessGranted == NO)` contains my segue code of `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addFriendsToMediaCaptureSegue" sender:self];`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{

[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

self.currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];



self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;


//Asks for access to Address Book.

ABAddressBookRef m_addressbook =  ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);



ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(m_addressbook);


__block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        @autoreleasepool {
            // Write your code here...
            // Fetch data from SQLite DB
        }
    });

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(m_addressbook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)

    {
        accessGranted = granted;

        NSLog(@"Has access been granted?: %hhd", accessGranted);


        if(accessGranted == NO) {

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addFriendsToMediaCaptureSegue" sender:self];


        }

        NSLog(@"Has there been an error? %@", error);


        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    });
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Comment: Did you override `prepareForSegue:`?

Comment: No I didn't, not sure if I understand. All I tried to do was "[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addFriendsToMediaCaptureSegue" sender:self];"

Comment: Did you tried `presentViewController:animated:completion:`?

Comment: You have declared the `segue identifier` in storyboard?

Comment: I am going to try presentViewController. What do I put for the input of presentViewController? Like how do I type the view controller's name?

Comment: write your code in `viewDidApear` and don't write `[self viewDidApear]` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @preetam i tried that and it did not work either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [whose view is not in the window hierarchy - email form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167242/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy-email-form)

Comment: error says:you are trying to present view from view which is not loaded yet i.e. adressbook

Comment: @preetam is right. `viewDidLoad` is too early to be doing this. You cannot segue to another controller until your view is actually visible.

Comment: @MikePollard so what should I do? How can I segue as soon as possible once the view is "actually visible".

Comment: Do it in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @MikePollard I just tried adding viewDidAppear as the first method implementation right after viewDidLoad. I put an NSLog with some dummy text inside of of viewDidAppear and the NSLog isn't showing up in the console. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewDidLoad:`

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    SecondViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
});;
```

Comment: This throws an exception in the console: "Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard' in bundle NSBundle" I even tried changing it to "Main.storyboard" just like it shows in my project navigator.

Comment: try using "Main" instead of "Main.stroyboard"

Comment: You don't have to write `Main.storyboard`, write only `Main` if you have `Main.Storyboard` in you bundle

Comment: I finally got your code to work perfectly, but it still ends up giving the same error as in my original question.

Comment: Edited the answer check it now

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure to have (in your storyBoard), a defined segue from current ViewController to destinationVC named addFriendsToMediaCaptureSegue.
2. Can you try to move your performSegueWithIdentifier: like this

   `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addFriendsToMediaCaptureSegue" sender:self];
   });`

Comment: Can you try to add a button in your VC, and perform the segue on click of this button ? Just to see if your bug is related to where is the code.